# In android after making wifi off and on i am loosing wifi connection information which is saved by by my app?

Tags: android, android-wifi

My app is connecting to a given wifi connection. After connecting i am able to see in **saved by app**. But when I do wifi off and on `restart wifi` that information **saved by app** is lost and therefore my app can not delete that network as from marshmallow app can not delete wifi connection created by user or other apps.
How to retain saved by myapp information in wifi restart or system reboot?

```
            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
            Log.d("SSID", networkSSID[0].toString());
            Log.d("Pass", networkPass[0].toString());
            conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID[0].toString() + "\"";
            conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass[0].toString() + "\"";

            int netId;
            //reconnect = false;
            netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Before https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbQ7R.jpg
After wifi restart https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjjoS.jpg

Comment: have you stored the connection information some where for persistence?                I mean shared preferences or data base?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. No i have not shred any info in shared preference. I am not sure what info to save.

Comment: you better post some parts of your code and we will tell you where to store it, or how to store it.                                                                                                Or you can check example of sqlite db or sharedpreferences in android and you will come up with alot of details and broader vision

Comment: I have updated code snippet where I add and connect to a wifi network.